# Calculus: Solving differential equation $e^y (1 + \frac{dy}{dx}) = 1$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm assuming this is will break down into a separable differential equation once some algebra has been applied but I can't figure out how to go about it.

It's the first time I encounter a differential equation containing $e^y$.

I started out distributing and then rewriting into $e^y + \frac{dy}{dx} e^y = 1$, don't know if that's on the right track. I also tried rewriting with natural logarithm ln.

Also, to solve the equation explicitly: $y(0) = \ln(3)$

Comment: $$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{e^y}-1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$e^y + \frac{dy}{dx} e^y = 1$ . . . .  . $(1)$

Let $z=e^y$, then $\frac{dz}{dx}=e^y\frac{dy}{dx}$

From $(1)$, $z+\frac{dz}{dx}=1$

Since the above equation is a first order differential equation, so Integrating factor (I.F.) is $e^x$. Now multiplying both side of the above equation by I.F. and the integrating we have

$ ze^x=e^x+c\implies z=1+c e^{-x}\implies e^y= 1+ c e^{-x}$

Given that $y(0) = \ln(3)\implies 3=1+c\implies c=2$

Hence $e^y=1+2e^{-x}\implies y =\ln(1+2e^{-x})$

Answer (score 2):

We get $$\int \frac{e^y dy}{1-e^y}= \int dx \Rightarrow -\ln(1-e^y) = x+C \Rightarrow y=\ln(1-D e^x).$$ Using $y(0)=\ln 3$, finally the solution is $y=\ln(1+2e^{-x}).$

Answer (score 0):

Two methods.  It's separable. \begin{align*}
1 + \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} &= \mathrm{e}^{-y}  \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} &= \mathrm{e}^{-y} -1  \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{e}^{-y} -1} &= \mathrm{d}x \\
\end{align*}

Alternatively, $\mathrm{e}^{y}$ is a little awkward, so try the substitution $y(x) = \ln (u(x))$, forcing $y'(x) = \dfrac{u'(x)}{u(x)}$.  Then the original equation is \begin{align*}
u(x) \left(1 + \frac{u'(x)}{u(x)} \right) &= 1  \text{, so } \\
u(x) + u'(x) &= 1  \text{,}
\end{align*}
which you should be able to tackle.  (Don't forget to switch back from $u$ to $y$ at the end.)